# Tkinter Exception Callback

Tags: python, tkinter, pytube

I'm still working on my little Tkinter project which is simple youtube video downloader
Every time i am trying to use the tkinter window it is giving me an exception callback and value error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "file.py", line 7, in downloadVid
    yt = YouTube(str(string))
  File "C:\Users\shaswat\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.descramble()
  File "C:\Users\shaswat\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 140, in descramble
    apply_signature(self.player_config_args, fmt, self.js)
  File "C:\Users\shaswat\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 225, in apply_signature
    cipher = Cipher(js=js)
  File "C:\Users\shaswat\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 31, in __init__
    var, _ = self.transform_plan[0].split(".")

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Here is the code

```
import tkinter as tk
from pytube import YouTube

def downloadVid():
    global E1
    string =E1.get()
    yt = YouTube(str(string))
    videos = yt.get_videos()
    s=1
    for v in videos:
        print(str(s) + '.' + str(v))
        s +=1
    n=int(input("Enter your choice"))
    vid=videos[n-1]
    destination=str(input("Enter your destination"))
    vid.download(destination)
    print(yt.filename+"\n Ha been downloaded")
root=tk.Tk()

w=tk.Label(root,text="Youtube Downloader")
w.pack()


E1=tk.Entry(root,bd=5)
E1.pack(side=tk.TOP)


button=tk.Button(root,text="Download",fg="red",command=downloadVid   )
button.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The error message, in other words, has an issue with there not being a "." in self.transform_plan.

Comment: the error suggests that the value that's being entered in tk.Entry() has more "." than it's expecting.   Please clarify what was entered in the tk.Entry() when it finally errored.

Answer (score 0):

Editing a line in the cipher.py, shown in the github link solved this issue for me.

> [`https://github.com/H4KKR/pytubeX/commit/f35b948afe3029ef60b427a1afd14e4551f2b7a7`](https://github.com/H4KKR/pytubeX/commit/f35b948afe3029ef60b427a1afd14e4551f2b7a7)