# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) and Tkinter/pytube problems

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pytube

I'm making a Youtube-audio downloader in pytube with tkinter for putting it in a graphic interface. It worked a week ago but not when I ran it today. I didn't know what to do so, here's the code I hope anyone can help me.
I fixed the cipher error in pytube and it drops that error and how I'm new, I don't know what is it about.

Version of python: 3.8

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import os
from pytube import YouTube

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Youtube to audio converter')
root.iconbitmap('000.ico')


root.geometry('600x400')

text1 = tk.Label(root, text='Youtube to audio converter:', fg="red", font=('TkDefaultFont', 18) ).place(x=150, y=0)

textEntry = tk.Entry(root, width=60)
textEntry.place(x = 120, y = 40)

text2 = tk.Label(root, text='Paste the link to the music video in the box and hit the button: ').place(x=115, y=65)

def download():
    link = textEntry.get() 
    print(link)
    yt = YouTube(link)
    t = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True)
    t[0].download()

button = tk.Button(root, text='Download', bg='#ff3d3d', font=('TkDefaultFont', 14), command=download).place(x=250, y =100)

text3 = tk.Label(root, text='Do you want it in mp3? If so, put the name in the box below (do not forget to put the extension .mp4) \n Remember: if the file is not in the same directory it will not be converted.').place(x=30, y=150)

textEntry2 = tk.Entry(root, width=60)
textEntry2.place(x=120, y=190)

def convert():
    archivo=textEntry2.get()
    if os.path.isfile(archivo):
        os.rename(archivo, archivo + '.mp3')
    else:
        text4 = tk.Label(root, text='That is not a file or file not found', font=('TkDefaultFont', 14)).place(x=170, y=280)
    

button2 = tk.Button(root, text='Convert to .mp3', bg='#ff3d3d', font=('TkDefaultFont', 14), command=convert ).place(x=220, y =220)

root.mainloop()
```

Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python3.8\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "InterfaceAudioDownloader.py", line 40, in download
    yt = YouTube(link)
  File "D:\Python3.8\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.descramble()
  File "D:\Python3.8\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 140, in descramble
    apply_signature(self.player_config_args, fmt, self.js)
  File "D:\Python3.8\lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 225, in apply_signature
    cipher = Cipher(js=js)
  File "D:\Python3.8\lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 31, in __init__
    var, _ = self.transform_plan[0].split(".")
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Thanks for your help again!!

Comment: Same issue as [tkinter-exception-callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63148957/tkinter-exception-callback).

Answer (score 0):

I remember reading that youtube constantly changes their API to prevent you from stripping the audio of videos. There is another package called youtube-dl which does the audio stripping. Every two weeks you have to update the package because the youtube API changed again. Most likely this is what you are also experiencing.

To answer your question it's possible that the return from transform_plan[0] changed, or anyone of your structures that this value depends on. You should backtrack through the code and find the change point, or create regression tests to easily find these problems next time.

Comment: I think that is what you have said YouTube has changed it's API, I have solved it, just installing pytubeX(for the ones who have the same problem) but the tkinter exception is still there but it works, thanks for your response. :)